# APK marca ningún dispositivo compatible en Google Play Developer Console

Tags: android, google-play

Acabo de publicar mi primer Aplicación en la play store, pero me indica que ningún dispositivo es compatible con mi APK.

He estado leyendo y la documentación indica que el problema está en el archivo Manifest.xml. Ya he realizado modificaciones pero sigue sin aceptarme dispositivos. Anexo el contenido del archivo Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="edmx.apptaxipassenger">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />

    <uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:persistent="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:persistent="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.ErrorActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <service
            android:name=".BGService.WaitingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_sync"
            android:label="@string/waiting_service">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/waiting_service">
                <action android:name="edmx.apptaxidriver.BGService.WaitingService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivitytmp"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps_activitytmp"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

También este es el contenido del archivo build.gradle:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "edmx.apptaxipassenger"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.01"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Podemos ver la application que publicaste en Playstore.?

Comment: Que dispositivos tienes, modelo y versión de Android

Comment: Hola. Elenasys y Webserveis. Me marcaba cero dispositivos. Pero en la respuesta de abajo ya quedó resuelto. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas usando librerías de apache es el único problema que podría provocar no permitir tu aplicación sea compatible.

```
<uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4"
        android:required="false" />
```

Puedes solucionar tu problema agregando como dependencia `commons-io` dentro de tu archivo `build.gradle` :

```
dependencies {
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    ...
    ...
    ...
    }
```

#### Actualización:

Encontré el mismo problema en el sitio en inglés puedes ver el enlace **[aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32747357/play-store-says-my-app-is-supported-by-0-devices-no-devices-are-compatible-wit)**. Existen algunas clases Apache que son [obsoletas](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client), te recomendaría revisar si [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi) también lo es para que consideres realizar el cambio.

Comment: ¡Gracias! Esa fue la solución. Me ahorraste horas de búsqueda.